# Flask App 500 Internal Server Error for chrome extension tool

Tags: python, flask, google-chrome-extension, gmail, phishing

Im new to flask and im trying to create a chrome extension tool for a phishing email detection system. I imagine the system works by clicking a Extract Button which will extract the sender, subject and email body text and a scan button which will analyze the extracted body text of the email to determine is it a phishing email.

I can extract the information of the email but when I click the analyze button it display 500 Internal Server Error in the console. Tried research some way to solve this but still can't.

backend.py

```
import traceback
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from flask_cors import CORS
import json
import logging
from http import HTTPStatus


app = Flask(__name__)


# Load the dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv("mail_data.csv")

# replace null value with null string
mail_data = dataset.where((pd.notnull(dataset)), '')

# label spam mail as 0; authentic as 1
mail_data.loc[mail_data['Category'] == 'spam', 'Category',] = 0
mail_data.loc[mail_data['Category'] == 'authentic', 'Category',] = 1

# Assuming your dataset has a 'text' column containing the email content and a 'label' column for phishing or not
X = mail_data['Message']
Y = mail_data['Category']

# Feature Extraction
feature_extraction = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=1, stop_words='english', lowercase=True)
X_features = feature_extraction.fit_transform(X)

# Convert Y values as integers
Y = Y.astype('int')

# Train the model
model = LogisticRegression()
model.fit(X_features, Y)


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def predict_phishing():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email_content = request.json.get('email_content', '')
        # Feature extraction for the input data

        email_content_feature = feature_extraction.transform([email_content])
        # Make prediction using the trained model
        prediction = model.predict(email_content_feature)[0]

        

        return jsonify({'prediction': prediction})
    # If the request method is GET, return a message
    else:
        return jsonify({'message': 'Please use POST method to make predictions.'})
    

   
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

popup.js

```
// Variable to store email subject, sender, and message
let emailSubjectSenderMessage = {};

// Function to send a message to content.js to extract email content
function extractEmailContent() {
  chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, (tabs) => {
    if (tabs && tabs.length > 0 && tabs[0].id) {
      const activeTab = tabs[0];
      chrome.tabs.sendMessage(activeTab.id, { action: 'extractEmailContent' }, (response) => {
        if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
          // Handle any errors in sending the message

        } else {
          // Check if the response contains emailContent
          if (response && response.emailContent) {
            // Extracted email content
            const emailContent = response.emailContent;

            // Extracted sender's email address
            const senderEmail = emailContent.senderEmail;

            // Store the email subject, sender, and message in the variable
            emailSubjectSenderMessage = {
              subject: emailContent.subject,
              sender: senderEmail,
              message: emailContent.body
            };

            // Display the extracted content including the sender's email address
            displayEmailContent(emailContent, senderEmail);
          } else {
            displayErrorMessage('No email data found on this page.');
          }
        }
      });
    } else {
      console.error('Invalid tab or tab ID not available.');
    }
  });
}


// Function to display the extracted email content
function displayEmailContent(emailContent, senderEmail) {
  const emailContentDiv = document.getElementById('emailContent');
  emailContentDiv.innerHTML = `<strong>Sender:</strong> ${senderEmail}<br><strong>Subject:</strong> ${emailContent.subject}<br><strong>Message:</strong> ${emailContent.body}`;
}

// Function to display an error message
function displayErrorMessage(message) {
  const emailContentDiv = document.getElementById('emailContent');
  emailContentDiv.textContent = message;
}




// Add a click event listener to the extract button
document.getElementById('extractButton').addEventListener('click', extractEmailContent);

// Add a click event listener to the scan button
document.getElementById('scanButton').addEventListener('click', scanEmailContent);


// Function to send the extracted email content to the Flask server for prediction
function scanEmailContent() {
  // Check if email content is available
  if (Object.keys(emailSubjectSenderMessage).length === 0) {
    displayErrorMessage('Please extract email content first.');
    return;
  }

  // Extracted email content
  const emailContent = emailSubjectSenderMessage.message;

  // Make an HTTP POST request to Flask server for prediction
  fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5000', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      email_content: emailContent,
    }),
  })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      // Handle the prediction result
      const prediction = data.prediction;

      // Display the prediction result
      displayPredictionResult(prediction);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('Error in predicting phishing:', error);
      console.log('Response Content:');
      displayErrorMessage('Error in predicting phishing. Please try again.');
    });
}


// Function to display the prediction result
function displayPredictionResult(prediction) {
  const emailContentDiv = document.getElementById('emailContent');
  let resultMessage;

  if (prediction === 0) {
    resultMessage = 'This email is predicted as a phishing email.';
  } else {
    resultMessage = 'This email is predicted as authentic.';
  }

  emailContentDiv.textContent = resultMessage;
}
```

I have tried to just used 'POST"

```
@app.route('/', methods=[ 'POST'])
```

But i just end up with error 405

Answer (score 0):

No need to do `jsonify()`. This should work

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def predict_phishing():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email_content = request.json.get('email_content', '')
        # Feature extraction for the input data

        email_content_feature = feature_extraction.transform([email_content])
        # Make prediction using the trained model
        prediction = model.predict(email_content_feature)[0]

        

        return {'prediction': prediction}, 200
    # If the request method is GET, return a message
    else:
        return {'message': 'Please use POST method to make predictions.'}, 400
```